# Using a table twice in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is so basic and I have no idea why this isn't working.
Error is:

> #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'course'

```
select c.title, p.title
from course NATURAL JOIN prereq c, course NATURAL JOIN prereq p
where c.course_id = p.prereq_id
```

I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax should look like this

```
SELECT c.title, p.title
FROM   course c 
INNER JOIN   prereq p ON c.course_id = p.prereq_id
```

IN case you want the rows to be retunred even tho there is not ID match then use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT c.title, p.title
FROM   course c 
LEFT JOIN   prereq p ON c.course_id = p.prereq_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
from course NATURAL JOIN prereq c, course NATURAL JOIN prereq p
                                 ^^^^^^^^
```

You have specified `course` twice in the join list. I would recommend ditching the `natural joins` and explicitly specifying the `join` criteria.

```
from course c1
  inner join prereq c
    on c1.?? = c.??
  inner join prereq p
    on c1.?? = p.??
```

Why is it that you need to join to the prereq table twice? Does a course have more than one prereq in a single row?

Comment: prereq has a course_id for a course and a course_id for its prereq and I'm trying to find a way to display each course and it's prereq if any. I wouldn't need the course table at all if it weren't the location of the title of the courses

Comment: @Sean ah. so there could be an unknown number of pre-reqs? ie course has a pre-req, that pre-req has a pre-req, and onward?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   select c.title, p.title
   from course c NATURAL JOIN prereq p 
   where c.course_id = p.prereq_id;
```